# annotation - How load Spring configuration class?

Tags: java, spring

I have simple project where I want run method `CarDaoImpl::save` from `Main::runApp`. I have class with `@Configration` annotation but my `@Autowired` field is null and I receive NullPointerException, because config class not load, how me fix this problem?

```
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private CarDao carDao;

    //psvm(){}

    public void runApp(){
        carDao.save(new Car());  //carDao is null
    }
}
```

*Configuration class*

```
@Configuration
public class BeanInit {

    @Bean
    public CarDao carDao(){
        return new CarDaoImpl();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How and where do you make Main class a spring managed bean?

Comment: I don't make this class as spring managed bean, how me make its?

Comment: So how do you expect @Autowired to work then? Initialize the Main class as a spring bean in the same way you initialized CarDao.

Comment: @gmaslowski I need add annotation to Main class? How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a constructor to Main where you create a new `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and then use that context to initiate the object.

```java
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    private CarDao carDao;

    public Main() {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeanInit.class);
        ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    //psvm(){}

    public void runApp(){
        carDao.save(new Car());  //carDao is null
    }
}
```

Please note that this will not make `Main` a Spring managed bean. For example, adding `@Transactional` or other aspect oriented annotations to methods in `Main` will have no effect at all.

I might be a better idea to make the caller of Main::runApp initiate the application context and let Main be a spring managed bean by including it in the configuration. You could then use `ctx.getBean(Main.class)` to retrieve the bean.

Comment: I can find variant solve the problem without using `getBean`. If use .xml config file in mvc  - getBean not used because .xml load during building project, how make its on not mvc project?